# Dynamic Naming for Image Saving from Google Chart's QR Code Generator

Tags: php, dynamic, qr-code, html-email

I've been trying to figure out how to finish this PHP script, and I think it would really help me and others looking to try and create a script that saves QR codes and then allows them to be sent to the person who created them. What I'm currently trying to do is create a QR Code Generator that emails a person a QR code generated dynamically from the name and email information information. Basically, the goal here is to do a PHP Get Request in the URL to display a user's dynamic PHP page on the site.

Please let me know if this doesn't make sense, I'd really appreciate any and all help and feel like this is a problem that others might need help with in the future as well!

```
 <?php
if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) { 
$hostname = 'localhost'; 
$user = 'username'; 
$pass = 'password';  
$dbase = 'database'; 

$connection = mysql_connect( "$hostname" , "$user" , "$pass" ) 
or die ( "Can't connect to MySQL" ); 
$db = mysql_select_db( $dbase , $connection ) or die ( "Can't select database." ); 

function clean( $var ) 
{ 
    $dirtystuff = array( "\\", "/", "*", "'", "=", "#", ";", "<", ">", "+", "%" ); 
    return mysql_real_escape_string( str_replace( $dirtystuff , "" , $var ) ) ; 
}  
$_POST = array_map( "clean", $_POST ); 

$name = $_POST['name']; 
$email = $_POST['email'];  

$sql = "INSERT INTO qrdb (Name, Email)  
                VALUES ('$name', '$email');"; 
mysql_query( $sql ) or die( "Couldn't run the query: " . $sql . " - " . mysql_error()                  

); 

mysql_close(); 
}  

$filename = "$HELPWITHVAR";
$width = 400;
$height = 400;
if (!file_exists($filename))
{
 $url = urlencode("DynamicURLHEREWithNameAndEmailInfoInAGetRequestFormat");
 $qr  = file_get_contents("http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=
{$width}x{$height}&cht=qr&chl=$url");
file_put_contents($filename, $qr);
}
echo "<img src=\"$filename\" width=\"$width\" height=\"$height\" alt=\"Scan my QR !\"   
/>";


$to = "$_POST['email']";
$subject = "QR Code for you!";
$message = "
<html>
<body>
<p>Here is your QR Code!</p>
<p><?php echo $filename ?></p>
</body>
</html>";

$headers .= 'From: <email@domain.com>' . "\r\n";
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put PHP tags in the email - they won't get executed!

You need to call the image directly

```
<p>Here is your QR Code!</p>
<p><img src="http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=
    400x400&cht=qr&chl=http://example.com/" 
    width="400" height="400" alt="Scan my QR !" />"
</p>
```

Replace example.com with whatever the URL is.